# Junit, Testing, Flyway: Can you combine @Before and @Flyway annotations?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, flyway

My code has a bunch of unit tests dealing with some DB that I would like to have reset before each test. I am using the @FlywayTest annotation to perform this reset.

```
@Test
@FlywayTest
public void unitTest1 {
}

@Test
@FlywayTest
public void unitTest2 {
}

@Test
@FlywayTest
public void unitTest3 {
}
```

This works fine, but is there a way to do this without having to annotate each test with FlywayTest? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
@Before 
@FlywayTest
public void setup() {
}

@Test
public void unitTest1 {
}

@Test
public void unitTest2 {
}

@Test
public void unitTest3 {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late anwser.

At the moment it is not possible but I will think about it if it is possible. 
Please add a issue to https://github.com/flyway/flyway-test-extensions/issues

One early design issue was that use made a whole database reset only per test class and use the annotation @FlywayTest on method level only as test exception.

florian